# VB 2010 .NET ComboBox How To Controll Object Whit This?

Tags: vb.net

I want to ask how to control objects with a combobox in VB.

So I have a combobox with two choices On and Off.

How can I enable and disable a textbox with an combobox?

Comment: `If SomeComboBox.SelctedText = "On" Then SomeTextBox.Enabled = True` ?

Comment: Private Sub Timer3_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
        If OrainsComboBox3.SelectedText = "On" Then
            OrainsTextBox7.Enabled = True
            OrainsTextBox8.Enabled = True
        End If
        If OrainsComboBox3.SelectedText = "Off" Then
            OrainsTextBox7.Enabled = False
            OrainsTextBox8.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: Its not work :(

Comment: Please do not put code in a comment.  Please _edit_ your question and add your code there.  Instead of `SelectedText` you might try `SelectedValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   you can try something like this

private Sub OrainsComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OrainsComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
            If OrainsComboBox3.SelectedText = "On" Then 
             OrainsTextBox7.Enabled = True
             OrainsTextBox8.Enabled = True 
          End If 
          If OrainsComboBox3.SelectedText = "Off" Then 
             OrainsTextBox7.Enabled = False 
             OrainsTextBox8.Enabled = False 
          End If 
            End Sub
```